# Can I make com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout clickable in fragment

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to make daimajia slidetlayout clickable. I set OnClickListener on SliderLayout but it not work. I also set clickable true in xml but still is not work.

here my code:-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_slider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
         android:id="@+id/slider"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         custom:indicator_visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment:-

```
mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);
mDemoSlider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int pos = mDemoSlider.getCurrentPosition();
        int id = image_link.get(pos);
        if(id!=0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ProductsCategory.class);
            intent.putExtra("category",id+"");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`com.daimajia.slider.library` has already has that built in event.
That will be available only on adding slider names.You should add names for each slider like this.

```
HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");

        for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getContext());
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra", name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
```

on the text slider view

```
textSliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(this);
```

and implement BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener.then we can override below code

```
 @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
//do something
    }
```

Comment: You must **implement BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener** on your fragment and then you can override onSliderClick, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Damián González Fernández I forgot to add that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer.  It is worth noting that on the method:

```
@Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
       //do something
 }
```

the BaseSliderView received by this method call may not be the current slider you just clicked.  You have to explicit call the getCurrentSlider() method to get the bundles you previously attached.  For example:

```
@Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
         BaseSliderView clickedSlide  = sliderLayout.getCurrentSlider();
         //get bundles attached  and or do something else
 }
```